# Django with Windows: Double backslash or front slash?

Tags: windows, django, syntax

So, I'm a beginner trying to learn django right now with "Practical Django Projects" with windows in eclipse pydev.

Anyways, main issue is I use windows and it seems to suggest I should use front slash in the comments for settings.py. But by default, the databases is already set to:

```
'NAME': 'C:\\Users\\dtc\\Documents\\Eclipse\\cms\\sqlite.db'
```

And while I was going through the book, it wants me to add this:

```
url(r'^tiny_mce/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
             { 'document_root': '/path/to/tiny_mce/' }),
```

But that path didn't work until I changed to double backslash \\path\\to\\...so I'm thinking I should just not worry about using double backslash.

It would be great if someone gave me a little insight on this because it's giving me a total headache while trying to learn django.

Comment: The double-backslash is perfectly fine, but Windows supports forward slashes too (and the reason they're recommended is twofold: they don't need escaping, and they're cross-OS-compatible), so I'm not sure how your second piece of code broke.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use python to get current directory and call a join on it with whatever you need to add. This will make it cross platform as python will take care of converting backslashes and forward slashes for you.

```
import os    
CURRENT_DIR = os.path.dirname(__file__)

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(CURRENT_DIR, 'templates')
)
```

That will save you on typing and the path will be correct. If you look in settings.py that django generates it will tell you to always use / even on Windows.

```
# Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or "C:/www/django/templates".
# Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
# Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
```

One last thing, your urls should use forward slashes because that is how django is going to use them.

Hope that helps

Comment: On Windows the above method creates paths with backslashes and so goes contrary to the Django docs.